# Add specific condition to some model queries in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have 3 entities(models):

- User
- Group
- Course

All three have relationships many/many to **Region** entity(model).

If the user is searching for any other Users/Groups/Courses

```
Group::all();
```

- I need to return only Users/Groups/Courses that have same **Region**.

What is the best method to implement this?
I'm thinking about redefining `::all()` method.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

Comment: You could set up a method in the Model class or just use the relationshit between group and user and apply `whereHas()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is creating a function in Region model to get groups/users/courses:

```
public function getGroups()
{
    return Group::whereHas('regions', function($q) {
            $q->where('regions.id', $this->id);
        })->get();
}
```

You need to have belongsToMany relationship defined in Group Model, which would be something like this if you are following the naming conventions:

```
public function regions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Region::class);
}
```

Then, you just need to call:

```
$groups = $region->getGroups();
```